# Powershell empty XML element formatted to be one line

Tags: xml, powershell

I need my XML format to be slightly different then the way Powershell saves it by default. Here is a code example:

```
[xml]$XML = New-Object system.Xml.XmlDocument
$Declaration = $XML.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0","UTF-8",$null)
$XML.AppendChild($Declaration) > $null

$Temp = $XML.CreateElement('Basket')
$Temp.InnerText = $test
$XML.AppendChild($Temp)

$Temp1 = $XML.CreateElement('Item')
$Temp1.InnerText = ''
$Temp.AppendChild($Temp1)

$XML.save('test.xml')
```

This results in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Basket>
  <Item>
  </Item>
</Basket>
```

My required XML should look the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Basket>
  <Item></Item>
</Basket>
```

Is this possible?

If i add `XML.PreserveWhitespace = $true` everything will end up on one line. And elements don't have the `PreserveWhitespace` property.

One solution i found is to add a space `$Temp1.InnerText = ' '` and then clean up the code in a second step. But i was wondering if there is a trick to have Powershell output empty elements on one line.
Unfortunately my target application that needs to read the XML will only accept the above required formatting.

Comment: I still have to explore the `XDocument` options. They currently give me an error. However the script is too big and complex to rewrite at this point. For now i'll be using a `.Replace()` before saving.

Comment: Thanks for following up; understood re rewriting; the _workaround_ from the answer may still work for you, though, as a slightly simpler alternative to string replacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bash
$Temp1.InnerText = ''
```

is **your attempt to force the XML serialization to use the single-line `<tag></tag>` form rather than the self-closing `<tag />` form**, because - even though both forms *should* be equivalent, the particular consumer of your serialized XML (Adobe) only accepts the `<tag></tag>` form.

Your attempt is based on distinguishing between a *truly empty* element - one that has no child nodes - and one that has an *empty-string* text *child node* (implicitly created by `.InnerText = ''`), in the hopes that an element *with child nodes* - even though the only child node is the empty string - *always* serializes in the `<tag>...</tag>` form.

Your attempt:

- ***isn't* honored** by the **[`XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument)** type's `.Save()` method (which prompted your question)

  - The specific behavior you've encountered was ultimately classified as *by design* - see [GitHub issue #31079](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31079#issuecomment-581686251).
- ***is* honored** by the LINQ-based **[`XDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument)** type's, `.Save()` method.

Therefore, you have two options:

---

#### Workaround, if you're given an existing `XmlDocument` instance:

If you construct an `XDocument` instance from the (non-pretty-printed) XML string returned by your `XmlDocument` instance's `.OuterXml` property (`$XML.OuterXml`), saving the resulting `XDocument` instance to a file uses the desired `<tag></tag>` form, *assuming you kept the explicitly added empty-string child text node in your code*, i.e, `$Temp1.InnerText = ''`:

```bash
# Creates a pretty-printed XML file with the empty elements
# represented in "<tag></tag>" form from the System.Xml.XmlDocument
# instance stored in `$XML`.
([System.Xml.Linq.XDocument] $XML.OuterXml).Save("$PWD/test.xml")
```

While this involves an extra round of serialization and parsing, it is a simple and pragmatic solution.

If the XML DOM object wasn't given to you and you have the option to construct it yourself, it's better to construct it as an `XDocument` instance to begin with, as shown next.

---

Alternatively, you can **construct your XML document *directly* as an `XmlDocument`**:

#### Constructing your document as an `XDocument` instance to begin with:

```bash
# PSv5+ syntax for simplifying type references.
using namespace System.Xml.Linq

# Create the XDocument with its  declaration.
$xd = [XDocument]::new(
        # Note: [NullString]::Value is needed to pass a true null value - $null doesn't wor.
        [XDeclaration]::new('1.0', 'UTF-8', [NullString]::Value)
      )

# Add nodes.
$xd.Add(($basket = [XElement] [XName] 'Basket'))
$basket.Add(($item = [XElement] [XName] 'Item'))

# Add an empty-string child node to the '<Item>' element to
# force it to serialize as '<Item></Item>' rather than as '<Item />'
$item.SetValue('')

# Save the document to a file.
$xd.Save("$PWD/test.xml")
```